# Which verb that describes financial loss better in the given context?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I'm struggling to find a word (verb) that fits in this context:

> Billy bought a book for 7 dollars and he sold it for 5 dollars. It ___ him since he should've sold the book more than 7 dollars to obtain a profit.

I can't think of another better example, but I think it should be enough to tell which verb I should use. I have phrases such as "gives a detriment to", "prejudices" or "will make him lose" but I don't think it will sound natural.

Comment: The only word that I can think that fits is 'cost'. Also the sentence is missing a word. It **cost**  him since he should've sold the book **for** more than 7 dollars to obtain a profit. It cost him 2 dollars to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the verb 'cost' about things that cause us to have to pay money, e.g. to ride a bus to work in my city costs (present tense) cost (past tense) me two UK pounds.

We can also use it to discuss something that causes financial or other loss, for example when we sell something for less money than we paid for it, or if we earn less money than otherwise.

> Cost (verb)
>
> 1 b to cause (someone) to pay an amount of money
>
> 2 a to cause (someone) to lose something

[Cost (Britannia Dictionary)](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/cost)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there ***is*** an English verb meaning ***cause [someone] to suffer financial loss***.

But a natural verb for the cited context might be, for example, *...it **annoyed** him...,* which could be metaphorically expressed as *...it **stung** him.* In which context it's worth noting that in...

> *He **got stung** by Bitcoin, which has halved in value since he invested his life savings in it*

...the highlighted words do actually mean "suffered financial loss". But if that verb is used in OP's exact context, ***to sting*** can *only* mean ***to annoy / upset***, not ***[cause to] suffer financial loss***.

Comment: "He became legendary for having convictions and acting on them, even when **it cost him money**, friendships, the intimacy of his family, and the goodwill of white audiences that would've preferred a Black performer bring the funny and leave current events behind." Review of movie about Dick Gregory on [Roger Ebert website](https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/the-one-and-only-dick-gregory-movie-review-2021)